# Does halacha define/suggest appropriate fees for the executor of an estate?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, beit-din-court, estates-inheritance, bava-batra

Is there a halachic figure on how much is appropriate for the executor to keep for their trouble in dealing with the estate? (I know the Gemara talks about selecting an *Apotropos*, fiduciary, if none of the heirs themselves are in a position to do it.) Would it be different if the executor is one of the heirs themselves? It sounds like most US states have some sort of percentage formula; is there some theoretical halachic number? Or would the executor have to basically take each case to a beis din to show how much work went into it?

And in today's American batei din, could the executor say "in the state of Connecticut, the law sets the default fee at x%, so when I was asked to do this and no one raised more questions, everyone should assume I should get x%?" (*Minhag hasocharim*, so to speak.)